# Winetricks can't read cd when installing game

Tags: wine, winetricks

I am attempting to Install Knights of the Old Republic using the winetricks wizard, and I keep getting stuck with a dialog which says "Wrong disk inserted, not found". However, I have my KOTOR disk inserted and can see it fine in nautilus.

[image: Wrong Disk Inserted]

When I put a different disk in the drive, it says: "Please Insert and Mount...", so I know it has identified the correct disk:

[image]

The other huge annoyance is that the window endless loops on me when I click "OK", so I could sit here forever clicking it and get no where.

Any ideas what is wrong, and/or what I can do to get this install working?

Versions:

```
Ubuntu 11.04 x64bit

valorin@thorin:~$ wine --version  
wine-1.3.18  
valorin@thorin:~$ winetricks --version    
20110417
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the winetricks verb, it seems as though it was designed for the 4 CD set of KOTOR rather than the DVD edition.

However, also looking at the winetricks verb, it seems that it doesn't do much more than click the buttons for you.  You should be able to install the "classic" way (by just opening the setup file on the disk with Wine).

There is one "workaround" in the winetricks verb for KOTOR: You may need to set a virtual desktop using winecfg inside if you run into weirdness in certain resolutions.

Comment: I actually have the 4CD set, not the DVD edition... But I did end up manually installing - although, the graphics never worked, so I gave up.